# Selecting a value in combobox that's populated from a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, compact-framework

I have a combobox being populated by a DataTable as shown below. I want to be able to set which item is shown. The value it is to be set to is a string that will be found in the "Id" column.

```
public DataTable list = new DataTable();
public ComboBox cbRates = new ComboBox();

//prepare rates combo data source
this.list.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Display", typeof(string)));
this.list.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string)));

//populate the rates combo
int counter = 0;

foreach (string item in dropdownItems)
{
    this.list.Rows.Add(list.NewRow());
    if (counter == 0)
    {
    this.list.Rows[counter][0] = "Select Rate..";
    this.list.Rows[counter][1] = "";
}
else
{
string[] itemSplit = item.Split('`');
if (itemSplit.Length == 2)
{
    this.list.Rows[counter]["Display"] = itemSplit[0];
    this.list.Rows[counter]["Id"] = itemSplit[1];
}
else
{
    this.list.Rows[counter]["Display"] = item;
    this.list.Rows[counter]["Id"] = item;
}
}
counter++;
}
this.cbRates.DataSource = list;
this.cbRates.DisplayMember = "Display";
this.cbRates.ValueMember = "Id";

//now.. how to set the selected value?

int rowCount = 0;
foreach (DataRow cbrow in this.list.Rows)
{
    if (DB.GetString(cbrow["Id"]) == answerSplit[1])
    {
        //attempting to set the SelectedIndex throws an exception
        //on another combobox populated NOT from a DataTable - this does work fine.
        this.cbRates.SelectedIndex = rowCount;
    }
    rowCount++;
}

//this doesn't seem to do anything.
foreach (DataRow dr in this.list.Rows)
{
    if ((string)dr["Id"] == answerSplit[1]) this.cbRates.SelectedItem = dr;
}

//nor this
foreach(DataRow dr in this.cbRates.Items)
{
   try
   {
     if ((string)dr["Id"] == answerSplit[1]) this.cbRates.SelectedItem = dr;
   }
    catch
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Ooops");
    }
}
```

Without FindExactString, FindString, FindByValue being not present in compact framework I am running out of things to try.

If attempt to use

```
this.cbRates.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

I get the following error;

```
System.Exception: Exception
at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
```

However, if I put the relevant code into it's own form for testing purposes I can set the selectedIndex without error.

I think these issues are linked.

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware that you can use the datatable directly as datasource?

```
        cbo.DataSource = table;
        cbo.DisplayMember = "Display";
        cbo.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Comment: I am, "list" is my datatable - this.cbRates.DataSource = list;
this.cbRates.DisplayMember = "Display";
this.cbRates.ValueMember = "Id";

Comment: Then, use the SelectedValue property: cbo.SelectedValue="234" (providing that "234" is one of the id's in the table)

Comment: I have tried that, and it doesn't seem to do anything. Tried using the variable that contains the string that = Id, and then hard coded it to be 100% sure it was using the correct value.

Comment: There must be something odd going on elsewhere in my code, as I've just thrown together a form with just the relevant bits on and it works properly.

Comment: I've had similar experiences. I don't think that the combobox works properly without a parent control (????) I created a combobox in a separate class. I tried to unittest it, and I couldn't get the damn thing to work until I instantiated a Form and added the combobox to this.

Comment: I think (looking at the error I've posted in the opening post) that it's a threading issue somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set SelectedValue? You have an Id, and you state that ValueMember is Id, then use it.

Comment: I tried   this.cbRates.SelectedValue = answerSplit[1];  and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, it's working but not too fast if you have tons of items:

```
foreach (object item in comboBox1.Items)
{
    DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
    if ((String)row["YourDisplayMemberColumn"] == "ValueYouWantToSelect")
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `SelectedIndex` by finding the item that exactly matches the specified string ComboBox.FindStringExact Method

```
cbRates.SelectedIndex = cbRates.FindStringExact("Value_need_to_Select") ;
```